# Problems using either pack() or grid() to fill a frame

Tags: grid, tkinter, pack

I am attempting to get the text inside the Label widget to be on the right hand side. I have set the anchor to E but unless I specify a width for the Label the text will not move.

I don't want to set a specific width for the Label widget as it should be the same width as the buttons in the frame below and as the size of the buttons may well change (this was only a trial with some sample gif's I had lying around).

Here is the code I am using:

```
from tkinter import*
class CalculatorFrame:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        f1 = Frame(parent)
        f1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        label1 = Label(f1, anchor = E, text = "0")
        label1.pack(fill = X)
        f2 = Frame(parent)
        f2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.buttons = []
        image_names = ["bus.gif", "plane.gif", "train.gif", "satellite.gif", "house.gif", "ship.gif", "satellite.gif", "plane.gif"]
        for i in range(len(image_names)):
            self.buttons.append(Button(f2, width = 90, height = 70, text=str(i)))
            self.buttons[i].img = PhotoImage(file = image_names[i])
            self.buttons[i].configure(image = self.buttons[i].img)

        i = 0
        for r in range(2):
            for c in range(4):
                self.buttons[i].grid(row = r, column = c)
                i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    game = CalculatorFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the containing widget, `f1`. As long as it's just a Frame with default grid values, it is only going to expand enough to hold whatever it's containing and center itself:

[image: Frame widget]

You need to specify a `sticky` value to move the Frame within its row or column. In this case, you can set it to `E` to move it to the east:

```
f1 = Frame(parent)
f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

Label(f1, text='0').pack()
```

More: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method